# Bootstrap popover on hover the links are not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

Currently I have the html links in the popover content.
The links inside the content are not clickable on hover and once focus is lost from the element which is attached to invoke popover on trigger:hover.

The popover hides immediately.
So, is there any way to keep the popover open and not invoking hide() until the focus is lost from the popover content and not the element which is triggering the popover?

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Ajinkya

Comment: plz provide some code!!

Comment: Show your code. Please take the quick tutorial on asking questions on Stack Overflow to keep this site contained with high quality content :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for this

HTML CODE:

```
<p>Click on button to see Popover</p>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="Facebook" data-html="true" data-content="<a href='https://www.facebook.com/carparknorth'>facebook link</a>"><i class="entypo-check"></i></button>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').popover();
});
```

it's display clickable popover

Comment: Once you move the mouse to click on the link, the popover will disappear. Which I think is what he was asking about.